# Looking for a CYOA that might not have been a CYOA about a shrink belt

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

Okay I think this book might be lost media at this point. I am looking for an interactive story that may have been a CYOA but might not have been that brand. It's about you getting a shrinking belt to help out a friend of yours who works at a particle accelerator to catch a potential terrorist that wants to use a belt he stole to steal secrets.

It looked incredibly old when I read it and that was like 15 years ago. I remember a few of the endings, one was you shrink into a small terrarium in the lab and are killed by an ant, another is you shrink further and get attacked by an amoeba and when you grow you are scarred and become a horror movie star. In another you are crawling in the ducts and this guy you are chasing is able to get in your ear after you get stuck and keeps singing show tunes until you give up on your mission.

The most memorable one was you go into the particle accelerator and you are fighting him on some protons and he pulls out and he threatens to reverse his atomic polarization with his belt and before you can stop him he gets hit by a proton and he turns into antimatter and explodes like a nuke destroying the whole facility.

It was a very cool adventure but I have been unable to find it for years, I remember the front cover looking very faded with a lot of reds, I think it had the particle accelerator on the front as well.

Comment: [Destination: Brain](https://gamebooks.org/gallery/xplr2.jpg)?

Comment: The term for a CYOA that isn't specifically a CYOA is "Gamebook".

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the CYOA book *[You Are Microscopic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/191008.You_are_Microscopic?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=l3kbslnpf5&rank=1)* by Edward Packard?

> On hand when a brilliant scientist unveils his latest invention--a
> machine that shrinks human beings--the reader is shrunk to a miniscule
> size and must fight such fierce foes as house flies

[This review](https://gamebooks.org/Item/388/Show#:%7E:text=A%20little%20knowledge%20of%20the%20scientific%20world%20can%20help%20you%20make%20better%20choices%20in%20this%20book.%20For%20example%2C%20I%20knew%20better%20than%20to%20jump%20onto%20a%20%22jelly%20blob%22%20in%20the%20pond%20when%20I%20was%20teeny%20tiny%20(it%20turns%20out%20to%20be%20an%20amoeba%20that%20chomps%20you%20up!)) mentions getting attacked by an amoeba.

> A little knowledge of the scientific world can help you make better
> choices in this book. For example, I knew better than to jump onto a
> "jelly blob" in the pond when I was teeny tiny (it turns out to be an
> amoeba that chomps you up!)

Comment: No I'm fairly sure it isn't this one, in fact I'm 95% sure it wasn't an actual CYOA but a similar brand. The book I'm talking about had a scientist and his assistant who initially contact you and help you. Also you never get eaten by a fly as far as I know but rather an ant at one point. Plus it seems to leave out the particle accelerator bit entirely.

Comment: I've searched *You are Microscopic* on Google Books. There *is* definitely a bit where you're in danger of being eaten by an ant - and from the small snippets I can see, I think you can fail to escape and actually *be* eaten!

Comment: Perhaps it could be *Help! You're Shrinking!*, also by Edward Packard? Including the text: *"for by now you are no larger than an ant . You're sure of that because an ant is heading toward you . It looks about four feet long . You hide behind a pebble."*

Comment: Or maybe the similarly-named [Help! I'm Shrinking!](https://gamebooks.org/Item/1703/Show)

Comment: [This page](https://gamebooks.org/explorer.htm) suggests *Journey to the Center of the Atom* and *Destination: Brain* as possibilities.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - You should post those each as possible answers